# How do I redraw airline after setting window-local variable

Tags: plugin-airline

`:help airline` states that variables related to sections can be window-local. The example from help shows how to do it for a plugin:

```
  function! MyPlugin(...)
    if &filetype == 'MyPluginFileType'
      let w:airline_section_a = 'MyPlugin'
      let w:airline_section_b = '%f'
      let w:airline_section_c = '%{MyPlugin#function()}'
      let g:airline_variable_referenced_in_statusline = 'foo'
    endif
  endfunction
  call airline#add_statusline_func('MyPlugin')
```

I want to know how can I do it from the window itself, or understand a proper way to configure `autocmd` for this purpose. After executing `:let w:airline_section_b = 'foo'`, the bar isn't updated. Is there a way to redraw it with new changes? I found `:AirlineRefresh`, but it just resets everything to defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to just run the function definition and airline function add for each window—that is, to do it *from the window itself* should require no modification other than removing the filetype check and changing plugin functions for your functions.

You could use an autocommand on the `WinEnter` event (I may have that wrong—someone feel free to edit and correct me): it could declare some kind of function or variable referenced in a global function to be used.

---

It occurs to me that some of the confusion is in the way the example references plugins.

A `.vimrc` file contains Vimscript, the special scripting language builtin to vim. It is, for all intents and purposes, an extension of the Ex commands—`:global`, `:join`, etc., are all valid Vimscript commands. And so are `:function` and `:autocmd`.

To summarize, you can just place things like

```
function MyFunc()
  echo 'do something here'
endfunction
```

directly in your vimrc.

(This ability to put Vimscript code in files is not unique to 3rd-party plugins or the `plugin` directory of the `'runtimepath'`.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's still not clear to me. Could you update your answer with an example? To be clear, I'm not trying to create a plugin, I just want to define regular autocmd and/or functions in vimrc.

Comment: See update @Thunderbeef

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for terminal buffers, which was my original intention. However, the answer is still correct, so I'll accept it.